# object filtering in template django

Tags: python, django

I have 2 class of model `post` and `comment` for loops in my template like this

I have a for loop like this

```
{% for post in posts %}

{% endfor %}
```

and I want to make filter like this `Comment.objects.filter(post=post.id)` in my for loop and get some value

how to write it properly?

Comment: you can filter in your views and pass comment objects to the context object.

Answer (score 2):

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
        {{ comment }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```